YouTube Embed Playback Issues in Safari Only. Built with Gatsby
I’m encountering inconsistent playback with YouTube iframe embeds on my Gatsby site, specifically in Safari.
Behavior Across Browsers:
In all other browsers, the YouTube videos autoplay and loop as expected (e.g., Chrome, Firefox).
Safari-Specific Issue:
In Safari, playback sometimes works fine for a few hours or on certain devices, but eventually fails. I often see a “sign in to confirm you’re not a bot” message, or a play button appears instead of autoplaying.
If I open just the youtube.com/embed/ link, it works fine.
Parameters Used:
The videos are muted, and I’ve configured the embed URL for autoplay and looping.
Troubleshooting Attempts:

Adjusted the referrer policy (tried strict-origin-when-cross-origin
and origin-when-cross-origin)
Updated CSP

In Safari’s console, I see errors like [Error] Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for', and some playback files intermittently fail to load, possibly related to the autoplay inconsistency.
Despite these adjustments, the problem persists, and I haven’t found a clear pattern to the failures in Safari. Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
My youtube component:
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

const createIntersectionObserver = (playerRef, options = {}) => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    // threshold: 0.1,
    rootMargin: '0px'
  };

  return new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    if (!playerRef.current) return;

    try {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        playerRef.current.playVideo();
      } else {
        playerRef.current.pauseVideo();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('Error handling intersection:', error);
    }
  }, { ...defaultOptions, ...options });
};

const handleObserverCleanup = (container, observer) => {
  if (!container || !observer) return;

  try {
    observer.unobserve(container);
    observer.disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('Failed to cleanup observer:', error);
  }
};

const YouTubeVideo = ({ videoId, title }) => {
  const playerRef = useRef(null);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [opts, setOpts] = useState({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    enablejsapi: 1,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      controls: 0,
      modestbranding: 1,
      loop: 1,
      playlist: videoId,
      mute: 1,
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      playsinline: 1,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      origin: window.location.origin // Explicitly set origin here
    }
  });

  // Effect for window-dependent options
  useEffect(() => {
    setOpts(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      playerVars: {
        ...prev.playerVars,
        origin: window.location.origin,
        widget_referrer: window.location.href,
      }
    }));
  }, []);
  

  // Effect for intersection observer
  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;

    if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
      console.warn('IntersectionObserver not supported');
      return;
    }

    let observer;
    try {
      observer = createIntersectionObserver(playerRef);

      if (container) {
        observer.observe(container);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('Failed to setup intersection observer:', error);
    }

    return () => handleObserverCleanup(container, observer);
  }, []);

  const onReady = (event) => {
    playerRef.current = event.target;
    event.target.playVideo();
  };

  const onStateChange = (event) => {
    // YouTube player states: -1 (unstarted), 0 (ended), 1 (playing), 2 (paused), 3 (buffering), 5 (video cued)
    if (event.data === 0) { // 0 means ended
      playerRef.current.playVideo(); // restart if ended
    }
  };

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <YouTube
        videoId={videoId}
        title={title}
        className="video-embed-object-fit-cover youtube"
        opts={opts}
        onReady={onReady}
        onStateChange={onStateChange}
        referrerPolicy="origin-when-cross-origin"
        allowFullScreen
        playsInline
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default YouTubeVideo;


My iframe output
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rnXIjl_Rzy4?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=rnXIjl_Rzy4&amp;mute=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;playsinline=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;enablejsapi=1" title="Hello, I'm Ian—a hyper-curious strategic creative operating at the intersection of digital and physical worlds, designing compelling human experiences that resonate across brand, product, and communications." width="100%" height="100%" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" playsinline=""></iframe>

Live site
